# Weird behaviour while manipulating Pandas dataframe within a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, iteration

I am unable to understand this behaviour. I have a dataframe, which is present as a "value" inside a dictionary `my_dict`

```
my_dict = {'a': pd.DataFrame({'x': [1], 'y': [2]})}
print(my_dict)
>>{'a':    x  y
        0  1  2}
```

Now, when I attempt a mathematical operation on the dataframe, that works, but a column renaming on the dataframe does not work -

```
for key, val in my_dict.items():
    val['z'] = val['x'] * val['y']
    val = val.rename(columns = {'x': 'new_x'})
print(my_dict)
{'a':    x  y  z
0  1  2  2}
```

The mathematical operation `val['z'] = val['x'] * val['y']` resulted in a new column `z` in the dataframe within `my_dict`

But the column renaming operation `val = val.rename(columns = {'x': 'new_x'})` has no effect.

Why don't I see a column `new_x` in `my_dict`. What is going on?

Answer (score 0):

change the assign to `inplace`

```
for key, val in my_dict.items():
    val['z'] = val['x'] * val['y']
    val.rename(columns = {'x': 'new_x'},inplace=True)
    
my_dict
Out[26]: 
{'a':    new_x  y  z
 0      1  2  2}
```

Comment: I would like to perform column re-ordering - `val = val[['z', 'y']]` , which would not work using the inplace suggestion. In either case, my question is to understand the reason behind z = x*y working and renaming not working.